# google app engine execute tasks in task queue with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using task queue for my php web app so I cant execute that tasks and they are not execute automatically.This is my code

```
    $task1 = new PushTask('/home/gettasks',array(),['method'=> 'GET']);
    $queue = new PushQueue('shaq');
    $queue->addTasks([$task1]);
```

I am using ***codeigniter*** framework.When I am check task queue with admin console in app engine it shows my queue as a *empty queue*

Comment: Do you have push queue `shaq` defined in your queue.yaml?

Comment: Could you post the content of both your app.yaml and queue.yaml files?

Comment: An empty queue most likely means it has worked. Interestingly, I cannot get the Tasks to work when using a typical CI URL in the URL parameter for PushTask. did you have to setup a handler in app.yaml?